# Bootstrap 3: Div does not work as before

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have `section divs` inside my form. And Each section can have multiple fields. It works fine with Bootstrap 2.3 css. When I replaced it with Bootstrap 3.0 css, all the fields came out of the section div. I tried inspecting the element but could not find any difference.

**CSS**

```
.section {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 39px 19px 14px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #649300;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="section" name="amount">
        <span class="section-title">Amount Information</span>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">

                Amount Of</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                Customer First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">

                Customer Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">

                Middle intials</label>
                <input type="text" name="middleIntials" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">

                Date</label>
                <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker" name="date">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                Street Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="address">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                City</label>
                <input type="text" name="city">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                State</label>
                <input type="text" name="state">
          </div>

          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                State 2</label>
                <input type="text" name="state">
          </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 has obsoleted the `spanX` classes. Replace those with `col-lg-X` classes.

See [this migration guide from v2.x to v3 of Bootstrap](http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide).

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your input tags, leaving them open may cause problems.

Example:
    `<input type="text" name="state"></input>`

Or:
    `<input type="text" name="state" />`